# Subtract in SQL Server code returning NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, subtraction

I'm having problems in this SQL server code, even using the ISNULL or COALESCE functions it keeps returning NULL, could someone tell me how to solve it?

```sql
CASE WHEN TIPO_X = 'F'
      AND TIPO_CALCULOX IN ('N','S','D')
      AND TRPR_COD_X IN (7,13,15,17) THEN CASE WHEN EVEN_COD_X IN (623,70623,947,70947,1871,71871,2697,72697,2871,72871,30623,30947,31871,22697,22871,20623,20947,21871) THEN CONVERT(int, (SELECT SUM(VLR_X)
                                                                                                                                                                                            FROM GMS_RELATORIO_GERAL
                                                                                                                                                                                            WHERE CHAPA_X = MATRÍCULA_DO_SEGURADO
                                                                                                                                                                                              AND EVEN_COD_X IN (623 + 7062 + 947 + 70947 + 1871 + 71871 + 2697 + 72697 + 2871 + 72871 + 30623 + 30947 + 31871)
                                                                                                                                                                                              AND MONTH(DT_COMP_X) = @MES)) - CONVERT(int,(SELECT SUM(VLR_X)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           FROM GMS_RELATORIO_GERAL
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           WHERE CHAPA_X = MATRÍCULA_DO_SEGURADO
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             AND EVEN_COD_X IN (22697 + 22871 + 20623 + 20947 + 21871)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             AND MONTH(DT_COMP_X) = @MES))
          END
          ELSE ''
    END AS RENUMERAÇÃO_DA_CONTRIBUIÇÃO
```

Comment: I *really* suggest you add some whitespace and line breaks to that query...

Comment: There's an `IN()` conditional expression in the middle there where the elements are separated by the addition operator rather than commas. This would be **MUCH** easier to spot if the code where formatted appropriately.

Comment: I very much suspect you are overly complicating the issue here. As for *why* you are getting `NULL`, I suspect because your first `CASE` expression results to `TRUE` on the `WHEN`, but the second does not. As the second  `CASE` expression has no `ELSE` you get `NULL`. Otherwise it might be that the `WHERE` in your subquery returns no rows, and so the `SUM` resolves to `NULL`. We have no idea; we can't run your query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I doubt this part of the code is as intended:

```
AND EVEN_COD_X IN (623 + 7062 + 947 + 70947 + 1871 + 71871 + 2697 + 72697 + 2871 + 72871 + 30623 + 30947 + 31871)
```

It's equivalent to this:

```
AND EVEN_COD_X IN (397898)
```

You probably want commas there instead.

Comment: *If* this does resolve the issue, I would suggest this question should be closed as a typographical error.

Answer (score -1):

Among your three `EVEN_COD_X IN` clauses, the last two are wrong : values should be separated with a comma (`,`).

```sql
CASE WHEN EVEN_COD_X IN (623 + 7062) -- It should be (623, 7062)
```

A good practice is :

1. to simplify your code (use CTE or temporary tables instead of doing everything in one query) ;
2. to use indentation (mistakes like this will become more visible) ;
3. for debugging, simplify it even more until it works.

Comment: These numbers in question refer to columns that have values, so I need to do SUM(n1 + n2 + n...) - (b1 + b2 +b...), but it returns null

Comment: Take any line in GMS_RELATORIO_GERAL and please articulate why you expect a non-null output. For instance : is its TIPO_X 'F' ? Is its TIPO_CALCULOX 'N', 'S' or 'D' ?

Comment: I strongly disagree about temporary tables. I'd use a CTE before a temp table.